# Can't get Codeigniter function to work

Tags: php, codeigniter, notice

Currently this code works.

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

public function index($renderData=""){  

    $this->title = "Needzilla";
    $this->keywords = "Needzilla";

            $this->_render('pages/register',$renderData);
    }
```

The moment I add this underneath it...

```
public function home($renderData=""){   

    $this->title = "Needzilla";
    $this->keywords = "Needzilla";

            $this->_render('pages/home',$renderData);
}
```

This happens.

[image]

Which points to this line of code.

```
    //data
    $toBody["content_body"] = $this->load->view($view,array_merge($this->data,$toTpl),true);
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add a function to the controller so that when I call that function it opens another page.... For example...

Getting from this page (after clicking sign in)...

[image]

To this page...
[image]

Full My_Controller Code Here.

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

//Page info
protected $data = Array();
protected $pageName = FALSE;
protected $template = "main";
protected $hasNav = TRUE;
//Page contents
protected $javascript = array();
protected $css = array();
protected $fonts = array();
//Page Meta
protected $title = FALSE;
protected $description = FALSE;
protected $keywords = FALSE;
protected $author = FALSE;

function __construct()
{   

    parent::__construct();
    $this->data["uri_segment_1"] = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $this->data["uri_segment_2"] = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->title = $this->config->item('site_title');
    $this->description = $this->config->item('site_description');
    $this->keywords = $this->config->item('site_keywords');
    $this->author = $this->config->item('site_author');

    $this->pageName = strToLower(get_class($this));
}


protected function _render($view,$renderData="FULLPAGE") {
    switch ($renderData) {
    case "AJAX"     :
        $this->load->view($view,$this->data);
    break;
    case "JSON"     :
        echo json_encode($this->data);
    break;
    case "FULLPAGE" :
    default         : 
    //static
    $toTpl["javascript"] = $this->javascript;
    $toTpl["css"] = $this->css;
    $toTpl["fonts"] = $this->fonts;

    //meta
    $toTpl["title"] = $this->title;
    $toTpl["description"] = $this->description;
    $toTpl["keywords"] = $this->keywords;
    $toTpl["author"] = $this->author;

    //data
    $toBody["content_body"] = $this->load->view($view,array_merge($this->data,$toTpl),true);

    //nav menu
    if($this->hasNav){
        $this->load->helper("nav");
        $toMenu["pageName"] = $this->pageName;
        $toHeader["nav"] = $this->load->view("template/nav",$toMenu,true);
    }
    $toHeader["basejs"] = $this->load->view("template/basejs",$this->data,true);

    $toBody["header"] = $this->load->view("template/header",$toHeader,true);
    $toBody["footer"] = $this->load->view("template/footer",'',true);

    $toTpl["body"] = $this->load->view("template/".$this->template,$toBody,true);


    //render view
    $this->load->view("template/skeleton",$toTpl);
     break;
}
}
}
```

Full Home Class

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

public function index($renderData=""){  

    $this->title = "Needzilla";
    $this->keywords = "Needzilla";

            $this->_render('pages/home',$renderData);
}
 }
```

Comment: Can we see your `_render` function

Comment: We need full My_Controller class and Home class, because some informations like constructor are here necessary.

Comment: I just added both for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to load a different view  into your existing template per say rather than route to another uri.

Let's say you have a route of "/home/"

In the past, I would create a template that had a dynamic area called "main_content". It looked something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body>
   ...   
   <?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

Then in my controller, I had something like this:

```
<?php
   if( not_logged_in )
   {
       $data['main_content'] = 'views/login_form';
   }
   else
   {
       $data['main_content'] = 'views/dashboard';
   }

   $this->load->view('/views/templates/page', $data);
```

All of the above php logic lived within the same route. It would just show two different views depending if the user was logged in or not.

Comment: You don't wanna do that kind of stuff in a view, rather use controller to it. E.g. `$data['content'] = $this->load->view('subtemplate1', array(), true);
$this->load->view('template', $data);` and then `echo $content;` in a view.

Answer (score 0):

You function name `home` is same as your class/controller name so it is automatically declared as the constructor of class as  described in [**php Constructors manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.constructor.php)

> Constructors are functions in a class that are automatically called
>   when you create a new instance of a class with new. A function becomes
>   a constructor, when it has the same name as the class. If a class has
>   no constructor, the constructor of the base class will be called, if
>   it exists.

Example code `Auto_Cart()` is constructor as your home function becomes constructor of your class you need to change the name your function

```
class Auto_Cart extends Cart {
    function Auto_Cart() {
        $this->add_item("10", 1);
    }
}
```

Another example your can find here [**Constructors and Destructors**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

> As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a
>   namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This
>   change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

Example code `Bar()` will work as constructor according to the php version

```
namespace Foo;
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // treated as constructor in PHP 5.3.0-5.3.2
        // treated as regular method as of PHP 5.3.3
    }
}
```

So when you tries to access the `home()` you are calling the constructor so your parent class's constructor should dealing with load property but now you have overrides parent constructor this generates the notice of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the parent's controller in your new class.

According to [codeigniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

"If you are extending the Controller core class, then be sure to extend your new class in your application controller's constructors."

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```